# What is this type of number?

Tags: java, types, numbers

I was browsing the source of TextSecure and curious what this assignment does on [line 80](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure/blob/master/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#L80).

From the repository:

```
  public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0ba7c0de; // get it?
```

I'm sure I've seen this before somewhere but never had a need to use it and don't really understand why one would use it.

Comment: it's a programmer 'joke'

Comment: At least three people have failed to get it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a hexadecimal number (this is denoted by the `0x` prefix - any literal that starts this way in Java will be a hexadecimal number.)

In this case, the decimal equivalent would be 195543262 - so it's exactly the same as:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 195543262;
```

There's a couple of other alternative representations this way - `0` as a prefix means the number is octal, and since Java 7, `0b` means it's binary. Hex is by far the most used of these though, since the octal notation is incredibly confusing and binary literals were a much later addition.

This is useful since sometimes it makes more sense to define a literal in another number base - I use hex extensively when I'm dealing with raw byte stream protocols for instance, because a byte is easily denoted by two hex digits so it's much easier to read when splitting them up this way. (Note, again just since Java 7, you can also add underscores in literals to further make it easier to split up for this context.)

In terms of this particular use though - it seems the exact value of the literal doesn't matter and it's just there as a joke (spelling barcode in [leetspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet).)

Comment: Barcocde? I think you will find it is BatCode. Make that 4 people...

Comment: or is it `badcode`? lol. barcode makes sense since it is named REQUEST_CODE..

Comment: @berry120, thanks for this great answer , hex digit was what I was looking for, along with octal/binary notation.

Comment: @MitchWheat Given the nature of leetspeak, I was always open to interpreting it more liberally given the context ;)

Comment: leetspeak : leet == 1337  kinda speaks for itself.

Comment: @kvseelbach: no that would clearly be 0x0badc0de;

Comment: @MitchWheat Perhaps you're taking the joke a tad too seriously! :)

Comment: yeah. the joke you still don't get!! :)